# How to remove input from from generated text in GPTNeo?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I'm writing a program to generate text...
I need to remove the input from the generated text. How can I do this?
The code:

```
input_ids = tokenizer(context, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
gen_tokens = model.generate(
    input_ids,
    do_sample=True,
    temperature=0.8,
    top_p=0.9)
strs = tokenizer.batch_decode(gen_tokens)[0]
```

Here the strs contains the input I've given...
How to remove that?

Answer (score 1):

The Transformers library does not provide you with a way to do it, but this is something you can easily achieve with 1 line of code:

```py
strs = strs.replace(context,"")
```

This is actually what I'm doing behind my [NLP Cloud](https://nlpcloud.io) API as it uses Transformers behind the hood.

Comment: It doesn't work always. It fails, I don't know why the output is changed.
 I used
strs = strs[len(context):len(strs)]

It wasn't working for sometime.

Comment: You are founder? oww... Thats nice!

Comment: I am ;) I sometimes noticed that, on rare occasions, GPT-Neo/GPT-J changes the input during text generation. It happens in case of wrong punctuation. For example if there's "hello , friend" in your input, it will be turned into "hello, friend" by the model. Maybe that's what is happening to you too?

Comment: I did also see!